# Grid View in a fragment

Tags: android, gridview, fragment

I try to set up a grid view like in this tutorial : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

But I want a fragment and *setContentView* in a fragment is not working. What I have to change to make it works ?

Thanks.

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `onCreateView()` method in your fragment like so:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
}
```